# Best way to OR 2 strings of 0,1

Tags: sql-server, bit

I have 2 string that just contains 0 and 1. I want a result string that bitwise OR them charcter by character.

```
DECLARE @str1 nvarchar;
DECLARE @str2 nvarchar; 
SET @str1= '11001100';
SET @str2= '00100110';

-- I want result to be : 11101110
```

The size of string is variable. I can use a for loop and OR the characters one by one. but the number of strings is variable and the size of them may be more than 1 million... Is there any better way than `FOR` loop?

Comment: Why are these strings instead of just binary data? You are using a byte to represent a bit. In any event CLR would likely be the best performing way by far.

Comment: the max string length is a million, or the number of strings is a million and the max length is short?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ideally you would be encoding this as binary.

`11001100` is a single byte `0xCC`.

Storing as `varchar` means it takes 8 bytes and declared as `nvarchar` it takes 16 bytes.

You could then also use CLR and bitwise operators.

Answering the question you asked though using a CLR function would likely still be by far the best performing way.

```
using System;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;

public partial class UserDefinedFunctions
{
    [SqlFunction]
    public static SqlString StringOr(SqlChars a, SqlChars b)
    {
        if (a.Length != b.Length)
        {
            throw new Exception("Strings should be the same length.");
        }

        char[] c = new char[a.Length];

        for(int i =0; i < a.Length; i++)
        {
            c[i] = (a[i] == '0' && b[i] == '0' ? '0' : '1');
        }

        return (SqlString)(new SqlChars(c));        
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Variant without using the loop - pure set-based approach (with recursive CTE) and therefore should be quite efficient compared to any kind of loop.
You can use this function to JOIN or APPLY it to the other data sets (tables or views)

```
-- function to split binary string to result-set
alter function [dbo].[SplitStringToResultSet] (@value varchar(max), @size int)
returns table
as return
with r as (
    select right(value, 1) [bit]
    , left(value, len(value)-1) [value]
    , 0 [pos]
    from (select rtrim(cast(
        case 
            when len(@value) > @size then left(@value, @size)
            when len(@value) < @size then @value + replicate('0', @size - len(@value))
            else @value
    end as varchar(max))) [value]) as j
union all
select right(value, 1)
, left(value, len(value)-1)
, pos + 1
from r where value > '')

select cast([bit] as int) [bit], [pos] from r

-- usage -------------------------------------------------
declare
    @OR varchar(20) = '',
    @AND varchar(20) = '';

select @OR = @OR + cast(n1.[bit] | n2.[bit] as varchar(1))
, @AND = @AND + cast(n1.[bit] & n2.[bit] as varchar(1))
-- XOR etc
from [dbo].[SplitStringToResultSet] ('11001100', 8) n1
full join [dbo].[SplitStringToResultSet] ('00100110', 8) as n2 on n1.[pos] = n2.[pos]
order by n1.pos desc

select @OR [OR], @AND [AND]
```

Result

```
OR          AND
--------------------
11101110    00000100
```

Comment: There are bitwise OR and AND operators ( | , & ). I think you can use them instead of your formulas. `|` <=> `n1+n2 - n1*n2`. `&` <=> `n1*n2`.

Comment: Since you are parsing the string in the function anyway, it would be logical to rewrite the function to accept two parameters Value1 and Value2 and OR them inside the function as you parse them. Thus you could avoid the `FULL JOIN`. BTW, parsing the string using recursive CTE is slower than other methods, like using a Numbers table: http://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-2

Comment: completely agree about the point that function can (and should) be re-factored and optimized logically for the particular case and I believe that author of the question will do it by himself. As for performance I  mean that recursive CTE is more efficient solution then procedural loop.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below

```
DECLARE @str1 nvarchar(10);
DECLARE @str2 nvarchar(10); 
DECLARE @result nvarchar(10) = '';
declare @counter1 as int = 1;
SET @str1= '11001100'; 
SET @str2= '00100110';
while @counter1 <= len(@str1)
begin
if (cast(substring(@str1,@counter1,1) as int) + cast(substring(@str2,@counter1,1) as int) >= 1)
set @result += '1'
else
set @result += '0'
set @counter1 += 1
end

print @result
```

Comment: Did you see this line in question **Is there any better way than for loop**

Comment: Ops, I didn't see that. but it can be inside defined function.

Answer (score 1):

Very cool question and solutions. I add another one using xml:
-convert boths string into xml where each char is a node 
-make them table valued with bit and ordinal
-join by ordinal adding bits

```
DECLARE @str1 nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @str2 nvarchar(max)
declare @s1xml xml
declare @s2xml xml

SET @str1= '11001100'
SET @str2= '00100110'
set @s1xml =(select cast(replace(replace(@str1,'1','<n>1</n>'),'0','<n>0</n>') as xml))
set @s2xml =(select cast(replace(replace(@str2,'1','<n>1</n>'),'0','<n>0</n>') as xml))


select case when a.bit+b.bit = 0 then 0 else 1 end from 
(select n.value('.','int') bit, 
        n.value('for $i in . return count(../*[. << $i]) + 1', 'int') position
 from @s1xml.nodes('//n') as T1(n)) a
join
(select n.value('.','int') bit, 
        n.value('for $i in . return count(../*[. << $i]) + 1', 'int') position
 from @s2xml.nodes('//n') as T2(n)) b
 ON a.position=b.position
for xml path('')
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the max string length is not a million but a much lower number, I would use a lookup table with 2 columns and 2^max string length rows with the char strings and corresponding binary values.  Then you can join your two strings to 2 instances of the lookup table and use the bitwise OR function on the results.

```
select bitstr1, bitstr2, b1.bin, b2.bin, b1.bin | b2.bin as OR_result
from
tblMillion inner join
tblLkpBin b1 on
bitstr1 = b1.str inner join
tblLkpBin b2 on
bitstr2 = b2.str
```